# My Django form is not rendering when I use Bootstrap's modal

Tags: python, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I have some trouble with rendering a Django form in a modal. I suspect it is because I need some Ajax to get the url in the browser but I don't know how.

Form:

```
class TrackedWebsitesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrackedWebsites
        fields = "__all__"
```

View:

```
def web(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrackedWebsitesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('/websites')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = TrackedWebsitesForm()
    return render(request,'dashboard/create_website.html',{'form':form})
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('web', views.web),
```

create_website.html:

```
<div id="addEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/web">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add website</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
     {{ form.as_p }}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
  </div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Some pics**

The non working modal form:
[image: Imgur]

Forms works when accessed directly through link:
[image: Imgur]

Can somebody help me out? I render the form fields manually but I just cut it with `form.as_p` otherwise the question would not validate because there was too much code.

Comment: can you provide us with the ajax code?

Comment: I don't have Ajax code yet...

Comment: I can open the modal, and when I hit add I can see a POST come through in the console, it is just the Django form that are not displaying. However when I acces the url directly through /web , then the form is displayed.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the form within the modal? Upload the code of the button event.

Comment: ```<a href="#addEmployeeModal" style="float:right" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i> <span>Add New Employee</span></a>```

Comment: I added two pictures to clarify the situation

Comment: Look at the answer try to make it as explicit and complete as possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that if you can open the modal and you do not visualize the formulary, it is because you are not loading it, try to do this:

Add this in your views.py

```
def add_employee(request):
    form = TrackedWebsitesForm()
    return render(request, 'your_template', {'form':form})
```

Add this in your urls.py

```
path('employee/add', views.add_employee, name='add_employee'),
```

in your html

Place this on the page from which you plan to open your modal and wrap your button in a div

```
 <div id="addEmployee">
    <a style="float:right" class="btn btn-success" >
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i> 
        <span>Add New Employee</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="addEmployeeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
</div>
```

Create a different html for the modal and add an id to your form

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="addEmployeeForm" method="POST" class="post-form" action="/web">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add website</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
               </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

in your js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let my_modal = $("#addEmployeeModal");
    const url_form = "/employee/add";

    $("#addEmployee a").click(function () {
      my_modal.load(url_form, function () {
          my_modal.modal("show"); // Open Modal
          $("#addEmployeeForm").submit(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default action
              $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "/url that handles the request/",
                  success: function (response) {
                      my_modal.modal('hide');
                  },
                  error: function (response) {

                  },});      
              });
          });
      });
  });
```

This answer will take you to the next question how to respond after sending the data from the modal. Therefore, you must do the following in the view you are handling the request.

First import the following in views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

And in the view that handles the request copy this

```
if form.is_valid ():
    ...
    response = JsonResponse ({"message": 'success'})
    response.status_code = 201 // indicates that the request has been processed correctly
    return response
else:
    ...
    response = JsonResponse ({"errors": form.errors.as_json ()})
    response.status_code = 403 // indicates that there was an error processing the request
    return response
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one is not working. I does not open the modal anymore on when I click the button.

Comment: Are you loading jquery-3.3.1.min.js in your scripts?

Comment: It did not work because if an external file is used and the urls are called in this way `{% url 'name_url'%}` it will not work. It is valid if the script is inside the html. But I have updated the answer. Check again. Just change the urls.

Comment: It works!! Thanks. How to make sure that the modal closes after clicking "add"? Right now it stays poppep up

Comment: You just have to add `my_modal.modal('hide');` In the function that manages the success status. I have already updated the answer with another question that may arise. Do not forget to vote up if it was your help.